# How to build conversational form with django?

Tags: django, fetch, bots

I am trying to build a conversational form with `Django`.

It will be used in landing page. The form questions will be loaded one by one as user answers them. And there will be some greeting and "human-way" responses to user input (such as "wow! you did a good choice!" after user selects one of the choices from form). The experience and look of the app will be like a real-time chat but user can only select one of the choices from form or upload a file/image.

**1.** Which technology is better to use for it? I am planning to do it with `Fetch`.

**2.** Since I want it to work without page reloading, how do I need to load `Django` forms through `Fetch`? Do I need to pass elements of it with `JSON` and construct it in client-side or can I just pass it as an html with `{{form.as_p}}` and display it in `HTML`?
Does these options make difference in matter of security?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about `Fetch`, but anyway I think it must be constructed clientside, but at first I would simply display the form in a template to get the ids of its fields and then use it in clientside code.
What about security - you'll need to pass the csrf token via your form.

Comment: Fetch is similar to XMLHttpRequest (AJAX). So page will not reload after form submit. Is it enough for it or do I need use WebSocket?